# Check if user has my Facebook app installed

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

My website uses a Facebook application which sends notifications to its users.

On one of my pages the user can subscribe or unsubscribe (depending on whether or not he is subscribed).

Therefore I want to check if the user is using my app. How can I do that? I guess I could do the following to see if the app can access the data:

```
FacebookClient c = new FacebookClient(accessTokenClaim.Value);
c.AppId = MYAPPID;
c.AppSecret = MYAPPSECRET;
dynamic access = c.Get("/me/permissions");
if(access != null)
{
//has access
}
```

The one thing I don't like about this, however, is the fact that I have to use an access token to see if the user has the app installed.

I would prefer not to use access tokens since they tend to expire.

In my database I store the Facebook userIds of all my website users.
Therefore it would be ideal if I could do something like the following:

> /get?appinstalled&userid=USERID

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current user ID - to compare it with your DB - you will have to access FB graph API using an access token. So I think there is no way to find any info about the user without using FB access tokens.
Edit: And do not worry about the expiration of the token, FB SDK will handle that for you. i.e. it will refresh automatically by the SDK. [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension):

> Facebook's official SDKs manage the lifetime of tokens for you. When
>   using iOS, Android or our JavaScript SDK, the SDK will handle making
>   sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.

And

> Access tokens on the web often have a lifetime of about two hours, but
>   will automatically be refreshed when required. If you want to use
>   access tokens for longer-lived web apps, especially server side, you
>   need to generate a long-lived token. A long-lived token generally
>   lasts about 60 days.

Comment: I see.
So if I store a Facebook access token the moment the user signs up to my app - I can just keep reusing it as long as I need (for weeks) without worrying about refreshing it ever again (unless of course the user has uninstalled the app)?

Comment: @JackAlexander, yes. That is correct. No more worries about refreshing the access token.

Comment: Great to hear! Thanks for your help :)